# how to store a collection of string as key and json as value in c++

Tags: c++, json

I am trying to store a collection of key-value pair in cpp, where `key` will be a string, as will the value - in my case, a JSON string representing an object.

Then I need to access this json object using Key1
For Example

Key1 = `name1`
Value1 = `{name:"Anil Gautam","age":25}`

Key2 = `name2`
Value2 = `**strong text** = {name:"Sharan Gupta","age":26}`

I want to access

```
{name:"Anil Gautam","age":25}
```

when I input "name1". What Can I possible do to store this kind of data in cpp.

Comment: Clarified that both the key and the value are strings. Wrapped only the key and the value in the example to indicate that the entire content of each is held inside a string. This seemed better than using single quotes, which would be invalid c++, or by escaping the inner double-quotes, which would only be the case if the provided data was found in a source file, which it almost certainly is not.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you should put the Value data into a structure:

```
struct Value
{
  std::string name;
  unsigned int age;
};
```

Now to have a `std::map` using a string and the value structure:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, Value> Map_Type;
```

Insertion is like:

```
Value v("Anil Gautam", 25);
Map_Type entries;
entries["name1"] = v;
```

To fetch the value:

```
Value v2;
v2 = entries["name1"];
```